# How can we interpret Groebner basis in a special case?

Tags: free-lie-algebras, lyndon-words

Let consider a free Lie algebra generated by $X$ with a set of relations $S$ such that the degree of leading monomial of relations in $S$ are greater than or equal to $2$. Let assume that we compute all possible compositions between relations in $S$, and we find a non-trivial composition, therefore, we add the non-trivial composition to $S$ and obtain a new set and call it the completion of $S$. In this case, can we claim that the our Grobner-Shirshov basis never include the relations with leading term of degree $1$, even our steps to get an $S$-reduced GSB be infinite?